# How to make synchronous call using Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I'm trying to get data using Retrofit call.enqueue ( DrawCircles() ), when i debug the values are there, but i think it does not waits and my function proceeds with the rest of lines of code. So the problem when I run it, the List of results (myListCoord ) is always null, how to make synchronous calls.

here is my code:

```
 doAsync {
        var a = DrawCircles()
        myListCoord = a.runCircles()
    }
fun runCircles(): List<Coordinates>? {
    val request = ServiceBuilder.buildService(TmdbEndpoints::class.java)
    val call = request.getCorrdinates()

    call.enqueue(object : Callback<MyList> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<MyList>, response: Response<MyList>) {
            if (response.isSuccessful){
                Toast.makeText(this@DrawCircles, "Succès", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                myListCoord = response.body()!!.locations
            }
        }
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<MyList>, t: Throwable) {

            Toast.makeText(this@DrawCircles, "${t.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

    })
    return myListCoord
}
```

Comment: It's a little hard to know what is happening given that you shown so little code here. Would it be possible to provide the code for the `DrawCircles` class? At least the constructor / init and the `runCircles` function.

Comment: thnx , I edited my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using `call.execute()` instead of `call.enqueue()` ?

From the [docs](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Call.html):

> `void enqueue(Callback<T> callback)`
> **Asynchronously** send the request and notify callback of its response or if an error occurred talking to the server, creating the request, or processing the response.
>
> `Response<T> execute() throws IOException`
> **Synchronously** send the request and return its response.

(Emphasis mine)

Comment: So help full, thnx